# regex replace all strings exclude special prefix

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace a tag but only, if there is not a special prefix. I need to replace the `href` but not the `data-orig`

```
$string = "Some gibberish here <a href='###REPLACEME:needed###' data-orig-href='###REPLACEME:needed###'>url</a>" ;
$pattern = "/###REPLACEME:(.*)###/";
$replace = "http://somerealurl.dev";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

I have no idea how I can realize this pattern.

Comment: So you want to replace the content in the `href` but not the one in the `data-orig-href`? Sounds like a job for a [negativ lookbehind](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Comment: fantastic point :D solution is `$pattern = '/(?<!data-orig-href=")###REPLACE:(.*?)###/';`

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please write up your own answer and mark it as accepted. It will prevent this question from showing as unanswered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
$pattern = '/(?<!data-orig-href=")###REPLACE:(.*?)###/';
```